# Character movement with the onscreen controller doesn't work for libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx, game-development

I have a PlayScreen class which handles all of the items that would be displayed on the screen for my game.

```
'''
public class PlayScreen  implements Screen {
private MyGame game;
private TextureAtlas atlas;

private OrthographicCamera gamecam;
private Viewport gamePort;

//Tiled map variables
private TmxMapLoader mapLoader;
private TiledMap map;
private OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer renderer;

private Miner player;

//Box2d variable
private World world;
private Box2DDebugRenderer b2dr;

MyController controller;


public PlayScreen(MyGame game)
{

    Gdx.app.setLogLevel(Application.LOG_DEBUG);
    atlas = new TextureAtlas("Mario_and_Enemies.pack");

    this.game = game;
    // create cam to follow character through map
    gamecam = new OrthographicCamera();
    // create a FitViewport to maintain virtual aspect ration despite device screen size
    gamePort = new FitViewport(MyGame.V_WIDTH / MyGame.PPM, MyGame.V_HEIGHT / MyGame.PPM,gamecam);

    mapLoader = new TmxMapLoader();
    map = mapLoader.load("map3.tmx");
    renderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(map, 1 / MyGame.PPM);
    gamecam.position.set(gamePort.getWorldWidth() / 2, gamePort.getWorldHeight()/2 , 0);

    world = new World(new Vector2(0,-10 ), true);
    b2dr = new Box2DDebugRenderer();

    player = new Miner(world, this);

    new B2DWorldCreator(world, map);

   controller = new MyController();
}

public TextureAtlas getAtlas()
{
    return atlas;
}

@Override
public void show()
{

}


public void handleInput(float dt) {

    Gdx.app.debug("DEBUG", "handleInput");

    if(controller.isUpPressed())
    {
        Gdx.app.debug("DEBUG", "upVelocity");
        player.b2body.setLinearVelocity(new Vector2(0,4f));
    }
    if(controller.isRightPressed() && player.b2body.getLinearVelocity().x <= 2)
    {
        Gdx.app.debug("DEBUG", "rightVelocity");
        player.b2body.setLinearVelocity(new Vector2(0.1f, 0));
    }
    if(controller.isLeftPressed() && player.b2body.getLinearVelocity().x <= -2)
    {
        Gdx.app.debug("DEBUG", "leftVelocity");
        player.b2body.setLinearVelocity(new Vector2(-0.1f, 0));
    }
    if(controller.isDownPressed())
    {
        Gdx.app.debug("DEBUG", "downVelocity");
        player.b2body.setLinearVelocity(new Vector2(0,-4f));
    }

}

public void update(float dt)
{
    player.update(dt);
    handleInput(dt);
    renderer.setView(gamecam);

    world.step(1/60f, 6,2);

    gamecam.position.x = player.b2body.getPosition().x;
    gamecam.update();
}

@Override
public void render(float delta)
    {
        update(delta);
        update(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());

        if(Gdx.input.isTouched())
        {
            handleInput(delta);
        }

        // Clear the game screen with black
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0,0,0,1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        // render our game map
        renderer.render();

        b2dr.render(world, gamecam.combined);

        controller.draw();

        game.batch.setProjectionMatrix(gamecam.combined);
        game.batch.begin();
        player.draw(game.batch);
        game.batch.end();
    }

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height)
{
    gamePort.update(width,height);
   controller.resize(width,height);
}

@Override
public void pause() {

}

@Override
public void resume() {

}

@Override
public void hide() {

}

@Override
public void dispose()
{
    map.dispose();
    renderer.dispose();
    world.dispose();
    b2dr.dispose();


}
}
'''
```

For the controller, I have my MyController class which displays the onscreen dpad and has listeners for when they are pressed.

```
public class MyController {

Viewport viewport;
Stage stage;
boolean upPressed, downPressed, leftPressed, rightPressed;
OrthographicCamera cam;

public MyController()
{
    Gdx.app.setLogLevel(Application.LOG_DEBUG);
    cam = new OrthographicCamera();
    viewport = new FitViewport (800, 480, cam);
    stage = new Stage(viewport, MyGame.batch);
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);

    stage.addListener(new InputListener() {
       @Override
        public boolean keyDown(InputEvent event, int keycode) {
            switch(keycode){
                case Input.Keys.UP:
                    upPressed = true;
                    break;
                case Input.Keys.DOWN:
                    downPressed = true;
                    break;
                case Input.Keys.LEFT:
                    leftPressed = true;
                    break;
                case Input.Keys.RIGHT:
                    rightPressed = true;
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean keyUp(InputEvent event, int keycode) {
            switch(keycode){
                case Input.Keys.UP:
                    upPressed = false;
                    break;
                case Input.Keys.DOWN:
                    downPressed = false;
                    break;
                case Input.Keys.LEFT:
                    leftPressed = false;
                    break;
                case Input.Keys.RIGHT:
                    rightPressed = false;
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });

    Table table = new Table();
    table.left().bottom();

    final ImageButton upImg = new ImageButton(new TextureRegionDrawable(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("up.png"))));
    upImg.setSize(50,50);
    stage.addActor(upImg);
    upImg.addListener(new InputListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            Gdx.app.debug("DEBUG", "upClicked");
            upPressed = true;

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            //upPressed = false;
        }
    });



    ImageButton rightImg = new ImageButton(new TextureRegionDrawable(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("right.png"))));
    rightImg.setSize(50,50);
    stage.addActor(rightImg);
    rightImg.addListener(new InputListener()
    {

        @Override
        public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            //return super.touchDown(event, x, y, pointer, button);
            Gdx.app.debug("DEBUG", "rightClicked");
            rightPressed = true;
            return true;

        }

        @Override
        public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            //super.touchUp(event, x, y, pointer, button);

            //rightPressed = false;
        }


    });

    ImageButton downImg = new ImageButton(new TextureRegionDrawable(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("down.png"))));
    downImg.setSize(50,50);
    stage.addActor(downImg);
    downImg.addListener(new InputListener()
    {

        @Override
        public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            //return super.touchDown(event, x, y, pointer, button);
            Gdx.app.debug("DEBUG", "downClicked");
            downPressed = true;
            return true;

        }

        @Override
        public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            //super.touchUp(event, x, y, pointer, button);

            //downPressed = false;
        }
    });

    ImageButton leftImg = new ImageButton(new TextureRegionDrawable(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("left.png"))));
    leftImg.setSize(50,50);
    stage.addActor(leftImg);
    leftImg.addListener(new InputListener()
    {

        @Override
        public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            //return super.touchDown(event, x, y, pointer, button);
            Gdx.app.debug("DEBUG", "leftClicked");
            leftPressed = true;
            return true;

        }

        @Override
        public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            //super.touchUp(event, x, y, pointer, button);

            //leftPressed = false;
        }
    });

    table.add();
    table.add(upImg).size(upImg.getWidth(), upImg.getHeight());
    table.add();
    table.row().pad(5,5,5,5);
    table.add(leftImg).size(leftImg.getWidth(), leftImg.getHeight());
    table.add();
    table.add(rightImg).size(rightImg.getWidth(), rightImg.getHeight());
    table.add();
    table.row().padBottom(5);
    table.add();
    table.add(downImg).size(downImg.getWidth(), downImg.getHeight());
    table.add();
    table.pack();

    stage.addActor(table);
}

public void draw()
{
    stage.draw();
    stage.act();
}

public boolean isUpPressed() {
    return upPressed;
}

public boolean isDownPressed() {
    return downPressed;
}

public boolean isLeftPressed() {
    return leftPressed;
}

public boolean isRightPressed() {
    return rightPressed;
}

public void resize(int width, int height)
{
    viewport.update(width, height);
}


}
```

I have debug logs that tell me that the buttons in fact do work and the the handle input is looped through. However my character does not move whatsoever. I have tried multiple versions of the handleInput method but nothing changes. I am unsure on how to fix this.

This is a link to my github repository 
https://github.com/jaketlee07/minerGame.git

Answer (score 0):

You need to add into your PlayScreen
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(controller);